# Golang Package for dynamodb with map , list and JSON support

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying save JSON objects as such in dynamodb ,using newly added support for JSON type(my understanding is JSON type is basically maps+lists) so that I can query and modify nested JSON documents.

I couldn't find any golang package for dynamodb with newly added data types support.

Any suggestion on this please ?

Comment: https://github.com/smugmug/bbpd or https://github.com/nabeken/godynamo don't fit the bill?

Comment: that package don't have support for new data types.Actually I was looking for some suggestions to amend/update package to add new types, or someone already working on this

Answer (score 2):

As of version 2 of the sdk a [specific package has been exposed](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue). This makes it a lot easier to convert any interface to `attributevalue.MarshalMap(r)`.

As per their example:

```golang
type Record struct {
    ID     string
    URLs   []string
}

//...

r := Record{
    ID:   "ABC123",
    URLs: []string{
        "https://example.com/first/link",
        "https://example.com/second/url",
    },
}
av, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(r)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal Record, %w", err)
}

_, err = client.PutItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String(myTableName),
    Item:      av,
})
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to put Record, %w", err)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put JSON in aws-dynamodb we first need to iterate through each attribute of JSON struct and convert it to dynamodb.AttributeValue in the following manner:

```golang
func (e *DB) saveToDynamodb(data map[string]interface{}){
    var vv=make(map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue)

    for k,v:=range data{
        x:=(v.(string))  //assert type as required
        xx:=&(x)
        vv[k]=&dynamodb.AttributeValue{S: xx,}
    }
    //s:=data["asset_id"].(string)
    params := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item: vv,
        TableName: aws.String("Asset_Data"), // Required
    }
    resp, err := e.dynamodb.PutItem(params)

    if err != nil {
        // Print the error, cast err to awserr.Error to get the Code and
        // Message from an error.
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Pretty-print the response data.
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To store a JSON or nested maps, you can store it in your struct as a `map[string]interface{}` and use `attributevalue.MarshalMap` before storing it into ddb:

```
type Record struct {
    ID   string
    JSON map[string]interface{}
}

r := Record{
    ID:   "ABC123",
    JSON: map[string]interface{}{
        "Parent": "aa",
        "Children": map[string]interface{}{
            "Child1": "foo",
            "Child2": "bar",
        },
    },
}

av, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(r)
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to marshal Record, %w", err)
}

_, err = client.PutItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String(myTableName),
    Item:      av,
})
if err != nil {
    return fmt.Errorf("failed to put Record, %w", err)
}
```